# php cli readline_callback_handler_install error

Tags: php, readline

When I call the function `readline_callback_handler_install` I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function readline_callback_handler_install() in /home/me/test.php on line 20
```

But I have php extension readline installed (and all other readline functions gives no error), and my version of php is greather than 5.1

```
me@laptop:~$ php -r 'echo extension_loaded("readline") . "\n";'
1
me@laptop:~$ php -v
PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.6 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Oct 14 2011 22:31:56) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by Derick Rethans
```

Does someone know what is happening?

Comment: PHP on the command line is not necessarily identical with the PHP that serves your web requests. Have you tried the above command on a web page?

Comment: @Pekka As I have specified in the title, this is a specific php cli error. Readline is a specific command line extension.

Comment: ah, sorry, I overread that in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this same error on the ubuntu machines I've tried to use this on.

Just as a note, I know Ubuntu build php using libedit, instead of readline. This may be one cause of the problem.

Comment: You give me the clue. In http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/php/php5-cli I found that php cli is build with libedit2 (>= 2.5.cvs.20010821-1)